# Customizing/Disabling Material-UI Dialog's Touch Mechanics

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

may somebody please help me customize/disable the Material-UI Dialog's touch mechanics? I have the **Cancel and Confirm** buttons, and that's just what I want to use to close the dialog. However, making a selection from a dropdown menu caused the dialog to autoclose according to the doc. And I couldn't see how to do that in the doc itself.

**The problem**

The problem I have is that the auto-closing is doing the job I want the cancel button to do. i.e: Closing the dialog and empty an array.

[image: Material-UI Dialog's doc]

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Any special reason to use the Material-UI **Simple Dialog**?

From your question, seems like a Confirmation dialog is what you're looking for :)

#### Simple dialog touch mechanism

> Touch mechanics:
>
> Choosing an option **immediately commits the option and closes the menu**
>
> Touching outside of the dialog, or pressing Back, cancels the action and closes  the dialog

In the other hand, matching your needs:

#### [Confirmation dialogs](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#confirmation-dialogs)

> Confirmation dialogs require users to **explicitly confirm their choice** before an option is committed. For example, users can listen to multiple ringtones but only make a final selection upon touching “OK”.
>
> Touching “Cancel” in a confirmation dialog, or pressing Back, cancels the action, discards any changes, and closes the dialog.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';

const options = [
  'None',
  'Atria',
  'Callisto',
  'Dione',
  'Ganymede',
  'Hangouts Call',
  'Luna',
  'Oberon',
  'Phobos',
  'Pyxis',
  'Sedna',
  'Titania',
  'Triton',
  'Umbriel',
];

function ConfirmationDialogRaw(props) {
  const { onClose, value: valueProp, open, ...other } = props;
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(valueProp);
  const radioGroupRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!open) {
      setValue(valueProp);
    }
  }, [valueProp, open]);

  const handleEntering = () => {
    if (radioGroupRef.current != null) {
      radioGroupRef.current.focus();
    }
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    onClose();
  };

  const handleOk = () => {
    onClose(value);
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      disableBackdropClick
      disableEscapeKeyDown
      maxWidth="xs"
      onEntering={handleEntering}
      aria-labelledby="confirmation-dialog-title"
      open={open}
      {...other}
    >
      <DialogTitle id="confirmation-dialog-title">Phone Ringtone</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent dividers>
        <RadioGroup
          ref={radioGroupRef}
          aria-label="ringtone"
          name="ringtone"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          {options.map((option) => (
            <FormControlLabel value={option} key={option} control={<Radio />} label={option} />
          ))}
        </RadioGroup>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button autoFocus onClick={handleCancel} color="primary">
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={handleOk} color="primary">
          Ok
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

ConfirmationDialogRaw.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  paper: {
    width: '80%',
    maxHeight: 435,
  },
}));

export default function ConfirmationDialog() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('Dione');

  const handleClickListItem = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = (newValue) => {
    setOpen(false);

    if (newValue) {
      setValue(newValue);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <List component="div" role="list">
        <ListItem button divider disabled role="listitem">
          <ListItemText primary="Interruptions" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem
          button
          divider
          aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-controls="ringtone-menu"
          aria-label="phone ringtone"
          onClick={handleClickListItem}
          role="listitem"
        >
          <ListItemText primary="Phone ringtone" secondary={value} />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button divider disabled role="listitem">
          <ListItemText primary="Default notification ringtone" secondary="Tethys" />
        </ListItem>
        <ConfirmationDialogRaw
          classes={{
            paper: classes.paper,
          }}
          id="ringtone-menu"
          keepMounted
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          value={value}
        />
      </List>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can have a look of the working dialog here:

https://4zgol.csb.app/

Hope it helps and if not, feel free to explain more about the problem or even add a code snippet :)

Comment: thx. I didn't take a close look at the confirmation dialog. I'll do and see if it can ease my work with the code I have currently.